# Can't navigate back in WPF using MVVMCross

Tags: wpf, xamarin, mvvmcross

When trying to follow the simple method of navigating "back" a level in a WPF MVVMCross app as described in the MVVMCross wiki (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation#how-to-move-back), it doesn't work.

I get the following message in the debug window when I call "Close(this)" from the ViewModel:

mvx: Diagnostic: 257.78 Requesting presentation change
mvx: Warning: 257.78 Hint ignored MvxClosePresentationHint

I then set out to manually close the view by extending the MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter, but couldn't figure out how to get a reference to the NavigationService using the ContentControl (MainWindow).

Regardless, it should work without this according to the Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is  still and issue, but I had a similar issue.  In your custom presenter, make sure you include the following line

```
base.ChangePresentation(hint);
```

This solved the issue for me, I had overriden the ChangePresenter method but was not calling the base.